# Facing trouble in margins from vb 6.0 to Crystal Report to thermal printer TTP 244 plus

Tags: vb6

I have set margins 0 by all side and also showing perfect preview without left margin then also printer is taking by default margin from left side during printing.

I have tried and check my other existing report also they are running well with same settings so not getting actual problem for this report.